# Linux CentOS server never dumps core

Tags: linux, centos, coredump

I have a CentOS 8 server that never dumps core. The same executable dumps core when executed in local environment

The core is enabled by my program as below

```
struct rlimit rlp;
struct rlimit newRlp = {RLIM_INFINITY, RLIM_INFINITY};
getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rlp);
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &newRlp);
```

`ulimit` is unlimited

```
# ulimit -c
unlimited
```

Core pattern is set and core directory is writable having 0644 permissions

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
/cores/core.%e.%p.%t
```

`suid_dumpable` was 0 but I changed it to 2 though it did not make difference

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
2
```

SE linux is disabled. The app is launched by `systemctl` as a service. Disk has plenty of space.

Any idea what is going wrong? As mentioned, same app dumps core when executed in development environment.